# SQL Server CE Delete Performance

Tags: c++, sql-server-ce, oledb

I am using SQL Server CE 4.0 and am getting poor `DELETE` query performance.

My table has 300,000 rows in it.

My query is:

```
DELETE from tableX 
where columnName1 = '<some text>' AND columnName2 = '<some other text>'
```

I am using a non-clustered index on the 2 fields columnName1 and columnName2.

I noticed that when the number of rows to delete is small (say < 2000), the index can help performance by 2-3X.  However, when the number of rows to delete is larger (say > 15000), the index does not help at all.

My theory for this behavior is that when the number of rows is large, the index maintenance is killing the gains achieved by using the index (index seek instead of table scan).  Is this correct?

Unfortunately, I can't get rid of the index because it *significantly* helps non-mutating query performance.

Also, what else can I do to improve the delete performance for the > 15,000 row case?

I am using SQL Server CE 4.0 on Windows 7 (32-bit).

My application is written in C++ and uses the OLE DB interface to manipulate the database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is something known as "[the tipping point](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/category/the-tipping-point/)" where the cost of locating individual rows using a seek is not worth it, and it is easier to just perform a single scan instead of thousands of seeks.

A couple of things you may consider for performance:

- have a filtered index, if those are supported in CE (I honestly have no idea)
- instead of deleting 15,000 rows at once, [batch the deletes into chunks](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/03/io-subsystem/chunk-deletes).
- consider a "soft delete" - where you simply update an `active` column to 0. Then you can actually delete the rows in smaller batches in the background. I mean, is a user really sitting around and waiting actively for you to delete 15,000+ rows? Why?

Comment: Thanks.  I had considered your batching idea but didn't want to touch the code if I didn't have to.  Now it seems like I must (sigh).

Comment: Also, the 15000 row deletion is taking 1-2 seconds.  Does that sound reasonable?

Comment: One more follow up question (sorry I am a noob w.r.t. DBs): when I changed my index specification to sort on the index columns (using ASC) it made *no difference* to delete performance.  Why is that?  Also, would sorting the index columns improve general query (SELECT) performance?

Comment: Because the important part of the cost of a delete is not finding the rows, it's actually performing the delete (there is I/O involved there, marking all the rows for delete, as well as any follow-on deletes, e.g. any index the columns are in, any foreign keys with cascade, the checks against whether deleting the row will violate any constraints, triggers, etc.etc.). As for the query performance, that depends on the query. Sorry, that question is way too generic for a yes/no answer.

Comment: So in my example, suppose I had a query like: SELECT * from tableX WHERE columnName1='<some text>' and columnName2='<some text'>.  Would sorting the index columns help in this particular case?

Comment: Not likely, because SELECT * will require lookups for all the rows (or, again, conversion to a scan), since the index does not cover all the other columns in the table. If you're using SELECT * you should forget about performance. Do you really need *?

Comment: [Check out this article](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list.aspx).

Comment: So I read your article on chunking the delete and while it had a *significant* positive impact on log size, the performance gains were less dramatic.  Is this just a consequence of the I/O bottleneck?

Comment: In your case I don't expect it to be much faster at all. The point is not to make it run faster (especially faster than 1 second!), but rather to block your users for far less time and to reduce the impact to the log (which *can* be substantially slower if your log is on slow disk and you have to incur autogrowths to cover the larger delete).

Comment: Thanks, and the to answer your other question: no the user is not sitting around waiting for those rows to get deleted so your "soft delete" suggestion merits serious consideration.